# Python socket.recv() returning new lines?

Tags: python, sockets, ipc

I'm fairly new to Python. I have two scripts running that are communicating with each other, but once the sender process stops sending bytes, the receiver process receives an endless stream of what decodes (UTF-8) to new lines. I've reduced the code as much as I could to keep things simple:

Sender Python script.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5409
s.bind((host, port))

data_to_send = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
print ('Got connection from ', addr,'. Sending data...', sep='')
for data in data_to_send:
   message = data.encode('utf-8')
   c.sendall(message)
```

Receiver Python script.

```
import socket

messages_received = 0
s = socket.socket()         
host = "127.0.0.1"         
port = 5409                 

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    incoming_message = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    messages_received += 1
    
    # This condition is just to avoid printing thousands of lines
    if messages_received < 10:
        print(messages_received, ':', incoming_message)
```

Receiver output.

```
1 : 1
2 : 23456789
3 : 
4 :
5 :
6 :
7 :
8 :
9 :
```

What am I doing wrong? I would ideally want the sender script to break out of the "While True" loop if the socket closes.

Comment: Of course it doesn't break out of the loop - you have not defined any condition that causes the loop to end.  Add as the second line of the loop: `if not incoming_message: break`.

Comment: I thought that would lead the receiver to receive blank messages even if the sender had yet to send more messages (for instance, send first message, wait a second, send second message, I thought receiver wouldn't receive the second) but I've made a quick test with a delay on the sender side and it works. Thanks for the quick response! As a side question can you tell me why it is that the receiver receives all the blank messages endlessly?

Comment: After the sending side has closed the socket, what else could the receiving side possibly return, other than a blank message?  It's endless only because you were mistakenly calling `.recv()` again after receiving the first blank message.

Comment: I could simply not receive anything (would just wait forever) or raise an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jasonharper pointed out, all I needed to do was to check for empty messages and break the loop as soon as that happens. When the sender doesn't send anything, the receiver doesn't receive empty massages, it just waits for a valid message, which I didn't know. The following code worked for me:

Sender Python script.

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5409
s.bind((host, port))

data_to_send = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
print ('Got connection from ', addr,'. Sending data...', sep='')
for data in data_to_send:
    message = data.encode('utf-8')
    c.sendall(message)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Receiver Python script.

```
import socket

messages_received = 0
s = socket.socket()         
host = "127.0.0.1"         
port = 5409                 

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    incoming_message = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    messages_received += 1

    
    if not incoming_message:
        break
    if messages_received < 10:
        print(messages_received, ':', incoming_message)
```

Receiver output.

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
5 : 5
6 : 6
7 : 7
8 : 8
9 : 9
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can try setting the buffer size on sender side :
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 1024)  # Buffer size 1024

if it dosent work you can try even dict format so you send data as json format.

Comment: I don't see how this would help, since clearly the buffer wasn't a problem (the entire message was sent). I didn't know sending a dictionary would encode it to JSON though, that's good to know!